# Access scope or service in ui router onEnter to check access (auth)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok, so I have a state for the url "/securepage" which I need to check whenever a user tries to access it. So I read there is an onEnter function I can use. But I cannot seem to get hold on the scope nor a service from there. What am I doing wrong?

```
        .state('securepage', {
            url: "/securepage",
            template: securepage.html,
            onEnter: function(){
                // if (!$scope.main.isAuthenticated) $state.go("/login");
                // if (!myLoginService.currentUser()) $state.go("/login");
```

Current options as I see it are to use resolve and/or check the authentication in the controller. But wouldnt an auth check be better placed in onEnter?

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a similar problem today. Spent a whole day and finally came up with a workable solution other than the ones already suggested here.

My main goal is to find easy and effective way to selectively secure certain specific webpages.  The security check needs to be performed before the HTML or any of the relevant controllers are loaded or called.  If the check fails, the page may be forwarded to elsewhere without any side effects from the other controllers.

I tried the other suggested approaches.  Each one has their own set of problems:

1. Using OnEnter:

   - There is no way to block ui-router from continuing with the state transition while making an async call to do the security check.
2. Using $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'):

   - The management of the states that rquire security check will become separated from the $stateProvider.state() definitions.  Ideally, I would rather see everything about the definition of a state defined all in one place.  Though this is not a showstopper, it is not ideal.
   - A much bigger problem is that the $stateChangeStart event is not being called for the initial loading of a page.  This one is a showstopper.

My solution is to use a resolve function to define a promise that will cause the view controllers to wait for the deferred to complete before they are called.  This work perfectly for blocking the controller from starting in an asynchronous fashion.

Here's a rough outline of the code I used:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    // Handler for Restricting Access to a page using the state.resolve call
    var accessRestrictionHandler = function($q, $rootScope, $state) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // make sure user is logged in
            asyncCheckForLogin(function(status) {
                if (status != "Logged In") {
                    // You may save target page URL in cookie for use after login successful later
                    // To get the relative target URL, it is equal to ("#" + this.url).  
                    //      The "this" here is the current scope for the parent state structure of the resolve call.
                    $state.go("loginPage");
                }
                else    // if logged in, continue to load the controllers.  Controllers should not start till resolve() is called.
                    deferred.resolve();
            }.bind(this));

            return deferred.promise;
        };


    $stateProvider
        .state('userProfile', {
            url: '/userProfile',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: 'userProfile.html',
                    controller: 'userProfileCtrl'
                }
            },

            // SIMPLY add the line below to all states that you want to secure
            resolve: { loginRequired : accessRestrictionHandler } 
        })

        .state(.... some other state)
        .state(.... some other state);

}]);
```

I hope this will help some of you out there.

Comment: Note that this works but requires 'asyncCheckForLogin' be asynchronous. If you have only local values to check and try to call `$state.go()` immediately it sometimes fails to change state (e.g. if you browse directly to the URL). Forcing the check to happen asynchronously avoids any problem. (e.g. `$timeout(function(){if (...) $state.go(...);});`

Comment: Great explanation of the pros and cons! If it were up to me, I'd make this the accepted answer!

Comment: This was so helpful - thank you! One small suggested edit: your resolve statement should be `resolve: { loginRequired : ['$q', '$rootScope', '$state', accessRestrictionHandler] }`

Answer (score 14):

Another approach would be to have a service/controller listen to the "$stateChangeStart" event. There, you could check if the called state needs authentication and reroute the request. Here's a snippet:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, nextState, currentState) {
    if (!isAuthenticated(nextState)) {
        console.debug('Could not change route! Not authenticated!');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeError');
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

`isAuthenticated` could hold the call to your services, check `nextState.data` for authentication-related properties, etc.

Comment: This doesn't fire when accessing the state directly via url.

Comment: This will get fired if you put this listener registration code inside your angular.module(...).run(...) call.

Answer (score 7):

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/190) and [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) example from their github page. It should give you some clues.

Comment: thanks, I get the $state and loginservice into the onEnter function and it works, but then next problem occurs : $state.go("login") does nothing. If I put it in the controller it works.

Comment: Yep, it seems you can't transition between states from within the onEnter function. I'm posting another approach in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but well I'd rather write it anyway. I prefer not touching the $rootScope wherever possible. Here's the code that I'm currently working on which sums up another solution for your question:

```
state('dash', {
                url:'/',
                views:{
                    "topNav":{
                        templateUrl:"user/dash/partials/top-nav.html",
                        controller:'logoutCtrl',
                    },
                    "sideNav":{
                        templateUrl:"user/dash/partials/side-nav.html"
                    },
                    "body":{
                        templateUrl:"user/dash/partials/body.html",
                        controller:'testCtrl'
                    }
                },
                onEnter: function(Auth, $state){
                    if(!AuthSvc.isAuthenticated){
                        $state.go('login');
                    }
                }
            })
```

I'm using JWTs to store the tokens on the localstorage by using ngStorage which gives a $localStorage service which I inject in the Auth factory I injected in onEnter

Answer (score -1):

probably you mean

```
.state('securepage', {
        url: "/securepage",
        template: securepage.html,
        //this is how you actually inject things to onEnter property
        onEnter: ['$state','myLoginService',function($state,myLoginService){
             if (!$scope.main.isAuthenticated) $state.go("/login");
             if (!myLoginService.currentUser()) $state.go("/login");`}]
         ....
```

Comment: Could you fix your snippet style?

Comment: is that ok for you now?

Comment: Where is $scope injected?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. All you're doing is formatting the onEnter function for strict mode (which would be better suited for a comment than an answer). In addition, the code has multiple syntax errors ("securepage.html" should be a string and there's an extraneous ` near the end of the last line), and this will not run anyway because $scope isn't being injected anywhere.

Answer (score -3):

I am using angularjs 1.3 with ui.router 0.2.10

I'm sure a lot has changed since this question was asked but as I had to figure it out myself and my search led me here...

As far as checking authentication you could do it like this

```
.state('securepage', {
        url: "/securepage",
        template: securepage.html,
        onEnter: function($scope,$state,myLoginService){ //THIS IS THE CHANGE
            if (!$scope.main.isAuthenticated) $state.go("/login");
            if (!myLoginService.currentUser()) $state.go("/login");
```

You can put pretty much provider/service/factory in the onEnter function to gain access to it, and this does work from inside the .config of the app.

Having said that, they (ui-router makers) suggests to use custom rule function handle it inside .$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-create-rules-to-prevent-access-to-a-state
I don't know why they do this instead of onEnter, maybe someone could expand on that.

Comment: I second what Pier-Luc said. Tested with angular 1.3.0-beta16 and ui.router 0.2.10